# Can I install wordpress on domain.com with some non-wordpress pages?

Tags: wordpress, dns

I have a website `example.com`. I have a generic landing page on domain.com that I want to replace with a Wordpress site, but I do have several webpages that I care about. They are all static pages:

```
example.com/hello
example.com/goodbye
example.com/hello/canada
example.com/hello/usa
example.com/hello/mexico (you get the idea)
example.com/help
```

Wordpress question: I want to install Wordpress on `example.com`, while keeping my existing pages in tact:

```
example.com -- wordpress
example.com/blog/a-blog post --  a blog post from wordpress
example.com/blog/another-blog post --  a blog post from wordpress
example.com/category/something --  a wordpress category
```

And still having existing non-wordpress page at:

```
example.com/hello
example.com/goodbye
example.com/hello/canada
example.com/hello/usa
example.com/help
```

I will install Wordpress on an AWS EC2 instance. My website currently exists on another server. Should I keep the Wordpress install on a separate server? Or use a single server to serve both Wordpress and the static page? I use hover to manage my domain’s DNS settings. What is my best path forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just placing the files in your root wordpress folder should work. And for simplicity's sake unless you have drastically different requirements of the static pages I would think they should be on the same server as the wordpress install.

Likely you'll want to separate out your styles/assets from your wordpress install (or use unique names) in which case each static page could have it's own folder matching the name of the page

```
/hello
    style.css
    hello.html
    hello.js
```

Alternatively you can just create template files for each of your static pages. You don't have to use the loop, sidebar, header, from the rest of the site in custom page templates. This would allow the static pages access to optimizations affecting your whole site: SEO, security, load speed plugins, sitemaps.

Probably don't need to say but just make sure to backup your static pages before your wordpress install. You can likely bundle these with your wordpress theme. But --at least a few years ago-- the directory in which you install wordpress needed to be clear before successful installation.